# How do I replace something that is on an append

Tags: python, replace, google-colaboratory, sentiment-analysis

I have to replace some words that are on a txt file, that I am reading. I separate them using an append, `[0]` is for the word that determinate the sentiment and `[1]` is for the rest of the text.

```html
# Opens the corpus
f = open("analise-sentimentos-2000-noticias.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8-sig")
linhas = f.readlines()

corpus_textos = []
corpus_rotulos = []

# Goes through 2000 lines
for linha in linhas:

  # Separate text and label/category/emotion
  item = linha.split(";;")

  corpus_rotulos.append(item[0])
  corpus_textos.append(item[1])
```

And I need to replace the words in append `[0]`, how can I do that? Here is some of the text I'm working with:

[image: link here to visualize some of the text]

I've highlighted as yellow the words that I need to replace, for example, 'alegria' should be replaced with 'positivo'. And in purple is the lines I need to exclude (if the line starts with the emotion 'surpresa', I need to exclude that). How can I do that?

For reference, I'm working with sentiment analysis using Google Colab. The txt was uploaded to my drive.

Comment: `append(item[0].replace('alegria', 'positivo'))`?

Comment: You could use a dictionary with all the replacements. `append(replacements.get(item[0], item[0]))`

Comment: The first alternative works well, thanks! :) but, this replace only the first occurrence? When I check, I see that 'alegria' still appears

Comment: I don't see why it would only replace the first one. You're doing it every time through the loop.

Comment: Was this supposed to duplicate every line the replacement is being done? In fact, every word "alegria" was replaced with "positivo" but, doing this, it also duplicated the line and created one with "alegria" and one with "positivo" :/

Comment: That would only happen if you kept the original `append()` instead of replacing it with what I showed. See my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check for `surpresa` to skip those lines. Then you can do the replacement in the category when appending to the list.

```
for linha in linhas:
    # Separate text and label/category/emotion
    rotulo, texto = linha.split(";;")

    if rotulo != 'surpresa':
        corpus_rotulos.append(rotulo.replace('alegria', 'positivo'))
        corpus_textos.append(texto)
```